# Degree of the map $S^1\to S^1:z\to z^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I want to compute the (topological/differential) degree of the map $f:S^1\to S^1:z\mapsto z^n$.

I've have shown that the degree of the map $g:\mathbb{C}^*\to \mathbb{C}^*:z\mapsto z^n$ is $n$. Is there a way to deduce $\text{deg}(f)$ from $\text{deg}(g)$? What are other ways to compute $\text{deg}(f)$?

Answer (score 0):

This depends strongly on your definition of the degree, but here is an attempt:

The preimage of a value on $S^1$ under $f$ is $n$ points. All these points are regular, and they all preserve the orientations of the $S^1$'s, hence contribute $+1$ to the degree. Summing these up one sees that $f$ is a degree $n$ map.

Comment: the point is: why "they all preserve the orientations of $S^1$"?

Comment: Can you visualize the map? The $S^1$ in the domain is wrapped $n$ times along in the codomain $S^1$. An orientation of $S^1$ can be thought of as drawing an arrow along the $S^1$. If you do this on both sides, you see that the arrows are aligned, which means that the orientations are preserved. You can also do this the calculus way by computing the derivative.

Comment: can you compute the derivative of this map?

Comment: @ThomasRot Sorry, but what would the derivative of this map be?